# How to remove unavailable server from Workflow Manager farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager

We had an old WFE crash, so we simply removed it from the farm and retired it. Now, several months later, I'm finding intermittent errors in the Workflow Manager client - apparently because it can't resolve the old server's name.

The server itself is gone, so I can't get on it and uninstall the client the proper way. I've been searching but so far all results only concern removing a server by accessing the server locally and uninstalling.

**How can I remove an obsolete & unavailable server from my Workflow Manager farm?**

---

***More Info:***

Using 'Get-WFFarm' on one of the active servers shows only the 5 active hosts. However, errors in the ULS logs show that the workflow client is attempting to resolve the old server name and cannot.

Comment: How many servers in the workflow farms?

Comment: Six total, five once I remove this server.

Comment: ia m not asking about the SharePoint but Workflow Manager farm, run this on the server where workflow manager installed...(Get-WFFarm).hosts

Comment: Yes, there were originally six hosts in the workflow farm

Comment: U are seeing old host in powershell output? Do u have load balancer infornt of ur workflow manager? Btw wfm support 1,3 or 5 servers in farm.

Comment: No - the server no longer shows up as a host when I do 'Get-WFFarm', but workflow errors in the ULS logs are saying the workflow client cannot resolve the name for the old server. I'll update the question with these details.

Comment: what URL you used to register the WORKFLOW URI? like https://url:12290?  Run this code $wfProxy = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy            
$wfProxy.GetWorkflowServiceAddress((Get-SPSite -Limit 1 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue))